# driver.getcurrenturl () does not take the correct url

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to learn selenium webdriver so I started with the basics but my `driver.getcurrenturl()` does not take the correct url.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://test.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("SelectedDomainName")).sendKeys("a");
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("b");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("#123");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn")).click();

    String Url = driver.getCurrentUrl();

    if (Url.equals("http://test.com/Home/Index")) {
        System.out.println("Login successful");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Login Failed");
    }

}
```

Comment: First debug question: What does the `driver.getCurrentUrl();` print out?

Comment: After login it will get the second URL details, the one "http://test.com/Home/Index"

Comment: I did not ask what does it get, but what gets printed. In other words, what do you see if you put `System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl())` inside the if check

Comment: are you sure you pasted the above command to your code?

Comment: when i print driver.getcurrentUrl after the button click event the url displayed remains the same whereas on the browser the url has changed to test.com/home/index

Answer (score 2):

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

This will take the current url, but you need to go to some url first so you need to mention:

```
driver.get("https://www.test.com/index.html");
```

After that you can put it in string and validate.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.test.com/index.html");
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
if(url.equals("https://www.test.com/index.html")) {
    System.out.println("Login successful");
} else {
    System.out.println("Incorrect details provided by the User");
}
```

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  
 WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://test.com/");
driver.findElement(By.name("SelectedDomainName")).sendKeys("x");
driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("y");
driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("123");
driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn")).click();

String Url = driver.getCurrentUrl();

if (Url.equals("http://test.com/Home/Index"))
{
 System.out.println("Login successful");
}
else
{
 System.out.println("Login Failed");
}
}

}

Comment: Where are you sending that x? under sendkeys

Comment: x, y and 123 are just the domain name, username and Password.

Comment: Th problem i am facing is that it wont take the current url. it takes the same URL that I am specifying in driver.get("https://www.test.com/index.html");

Comment: But where are you passing these things on test.com. I went to that website, there i couln't find Domainname, UserName, Loginbtn. I ran your code, it gives me error as no such element found. SO please tell where are you sending keys on test.com page?.

Comment: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
  //Click on tags
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav-tags']")).click();
  String Url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
  System.out.println(Url);
  
  if (Url.equals("http://stackoverflow.com/")) 
  { 
  System.out.println("Home page"); 
  } 
 else 
  { 
   System.out.println("Tags PAge"); 
  } 
Try this. Hope you can relate

Comment: Thanks, I did the same thing, I cant share the site link but i did            String Url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
System.out.println(Url); but the result set again gave me https://www.test.com. I don't know why its not picking up the current Url " http://test.com/Home/Index"

Comment: and since its not taking the current URL it fails every time

Comment: any help from you side?

Comment: See i need exact test case what are you doing where? it is very important for me to find where this is:

Comment: driver.findElement(By.name("SelectedDomainName")).sendKeys("x"); driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("y"); driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("123"); driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn")).click();

Comment: Only thing i can show that i gave you example of stackoverflow in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

What URL are you expecting to get? Make sure you navigate to that URL first (see below) and that the navigation has been complete.

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Before you compare it to other string, print it out and see what's there. Just note that if you are trying to obtain the URL before the navigation has taken place, it will return `about:blank` string to you.

Comment: @ShayniSood the other question I asked is what are you expection and what are you getting?

Comment: I am expecting to get "http://test.com/Home/Index" but I am not getting this in  driver.getcurrent(URL). Instead I am getting :http://test.com". This is the URL I am launching the fireforx browser with.

Comment: Any help from your side??

Comment: @ShayniSood looking at your example and the webpage that you are working with makes me think that you have your script wrong as I can't see how you are supposed to get to that url in the first place. I was unable to even do that manually. Please review your scenario.